# Why ARGV.shift in rails startup script

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, command-line-arguments

The start-up script for rails has the following code:

```
require 'rubygems'

version = ">= 0"

if ARGV.first
  str = ARGV.first
  str = str.dup.force_encoding("BINARY") if str.respond_to? :force_encoding
  if str =~ /\A_(.*)_\z/ and Gem::Version.correct?($1) then
    version = $1
    ARGV.shift
  end
end

gem 'railties', version
load Gem.bin_path('railties', 'rails', version)
```

Why are we doing `ARGV.shift` ? Is it just a canonical way of dealing with ARGV after we have consumed an argument or do we need to do it for some reason?

Comment: My suspicion is that the Gem being loaded in the last line uses arguments passed through `ARGV`, and that the first argument, which is for the start-up script itself, needs to be removed from `ARGV` before control is passed to Rails to prevent Rails from complaining about an unknown argument.

Comment: Yes that makes sense. This wrapper code is added to all gems to give this version setting capability. Did not realize ARGV constant was being passed to Rails. Thanks

Comment: If that answers your question, I can make it an answer.

Comment: Yes please go ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely this is because Rails uses `ARGV` to read its own command line arguments. If the start-up script failed to remove its argument (the first one) from `ARGV` before starting Rails, Rails would complain about an unexpected first argument, and probably abort.